# Play: Exclude certain tables from being managed by the evolutions?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3, playframework-evolutions

I have a Scala Play app over a MySQL instance. I store my evolutions as `conf/evolutions/$db/$step.sql` files. However, some of my tables are dynamic i.e. their schema may be modified during the runtime of the Play app. What is the best way to exclude these tables from Play's evolutions framework?

I have couple of choices and none of them look especially elegant:

1) Move all the offending tables to a separate database where the evolutions plugin is disabled - This is not that great since I have to move all related tables that have foreign key constraints out of the current database too.

2) Somehow override Play's evolutions framework - Unfortunately, Play's evolution framework is not modular nor is it extendable. I was hoping it would have some Scala or Java hooks for `def onUp(tableName: String)` and `def onDown(tableName: String)` that I can override but Play's evolutions framework has no such nice abstractions it seems and is quite monolithic.

3) I know Play creates an entry in a table called `play_evolutions` - I can modify that table from my app in `onStart` to manually take out all offending table related stuff. That would work but is very hackish and has hard dependency on Play's internal representation/handling of schema changes.

4) Simply move all offending table sql statements to `conf/evolutions/$db/ignore_evolution_$step.sql`- This way these tables are out of the watchful eyes of the evolutions framework but I essentially have to roll my own framework to parse these files and execute them.

5) Anything else I missed?

Comment: Or use a different evolution library, such as http://flywaydb.org/ ?